# Не работает Preview AndroidStudio при использовании GridView и ListView

Tags: android-studio, xml, listview, gridview, preview

Preview работает с другими элементами, но не отображает GridView и ListView. Новичок в Adnroid Studio, только начинаю изучать. По данной проблеме ничего не нашел. Код:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NumbersActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">
        <!--Для GridView-->
    </GridView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot Android Studio]

Comment: По идее, всё у вас отображается, просто отображать нечего. Попробуйте вот это добавить в разметку в GridView: `tools:listitem="@layout/grid_item"`, где `grid_item` - разметка вашей ячейки для GridView

Comment: Все работает, как должно, просто это всего лишь превью (статическая картинка на основе рендеринга xml-разметки), а не исполнямый код,  вы не можете увидеть в превью содержимое виджетов, заполняемых динамически через код (в данном случае код адаптера), только то, что указано в самом xml. Но если вам очень хочется, вы можете "в ручную" нарисовать их через [инструменты пространства имен tools](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-tools-attributes-listitem-sample-data-rocks-bbf49aaa9f07). При этом нужно понимать, что с реальным исполняемым кодом будет столько общего, насколько хорошо вы его повторите